# Condition number of a matrix bounded from below and above?

Tags: matrices, upper-lower-bounds, condition-number

Is condition number of an invertible matrix bounded from below? And is condition number always bounded from above for an invertible matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices) of a matrix $A$ can be characterized by
$$\kappa(A)=\frac{\lambda_{\max}}{\lambda_{\min}}$$
where $$\lambda_\min := \min \{|\lambda |: \lambda \in \sigma(A)\},\quad \lambda_\max := \max \{|\lambda |: \lambda \in \sigma(A)\},$$
and $\sigma(A)$ is the [spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_matrix) of $A$. So it is clear that $\kappa(A) \geq 1$ for every $A$ since $\lambda_\min\leq \lambda_\max$, however consider the matrix

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} \delta & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
then for $\delta > 1$ we have $\lambda_\min=1$,and $\lambda_\max= \delta$ so that 
$$\kappa(A) = \delta \to \infty$$
as $\delta \to \infty$. So it is not bounded from above.